# EntityNotFoundException Even if the entity is actually available

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, exception

I have a table with name `branch` and the model class is `Branch.java`

When I do a getSingleResult on `id` 515, `EntityManager` is throwing a weird error as below

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
    .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM branch t where t.enabled=true and t.id = :value1",
        Branch.class);
query.setParameter("value1", id);
branch = (Branch) query.getSingleResult();
```

StackTrace:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.urbanbuz.model.Branch with id 982
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:155)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:210)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1078)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1005)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:651)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:471)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:134)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1103)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:960)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3887)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:458)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:427)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
>           at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1078)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1005)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:651)
>           at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:471)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:134)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1103)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:960)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1783)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:231)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:283)
>           at com.urbanbuz.dao.BranchDAO.findById(BranchDAO.java:110)
>           at com.urbanbuz.dao.BranchDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$47398e8.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
>        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
>           at com.urbanbuz.dao.BranchDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b0e2bae8.findById()
>           at com.urbanbuz.service.BranchService.getBranch(BranchService.java:42)
>           at com.urbanbuz.component.SignupComponent.signUpUpload(SignupComponent.java:3030)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1180.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.urbanbuz.mq.MessageProcessor.processMessage(MessageProcessor.java:112)
>           at com.urbanbuz.mq.CoreController.handleOrder(CoreController.java:22)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:327)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:253)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:694)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:617)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1196)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:600)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:960)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:944)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In question you said id=515 but error has id=982. "javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.urbanbuz.model.Branch with id 982"

Comment: Yes,The error is thrown as id 982 for id 515 ,that's why I had mentioned the error as weird.The same query for other ids works fine.

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but what gives the query when you run it directly on the database? It looks like a kind of reference error, like if an object is expected to be found is empty.

Comment: When I run the same query directly on the database, it gives the right response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch.class had a wrong mapping with Device.java(device table) and device table had an entry with branchId 982,which does not exist.
Removing the wrong mapping of Device.java and deleting the wrong record in device table solved the issue.